# Count values as per required pattern in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

[image]

User ID - 39 is repeated but there are different incentive plans for 39. I want the result as shown in desired output.

Comment: Make a unique() list and then countif(). Even join the ID with plan name.

Comment: There is no question here. Please refer to [ask] a question. Currently this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your data is sorted by User ID and Incentive Plan. In that case you may benefit from IF and logical thinking:

[image]

```
=IF(A2<>A1;1;IF(B2=B1;C1;C1+1))
```

Please, notice this formula will work **only** if your data is sorted like the one in your image. If you change this order, the formula **won't work properly**.

Answer (score 1):

With ***Excel-365*** can try-

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B2,$A$2:$A2=A2))<>""))
```

[image]